Sentence structure 'The furniture arrives fully assembled.'
I have a questions about sentence structure.

The furniture arrives fully assembled.

I understand what it means, but what's the function of 'fully assembled'?
It doesn't seem to modify the verb, but it looks connected like subject complement 'the furniture'.
Or
The furniture arrives (with being) fully assembled.?

You are right when you say it is connected to the subject. "Fully assembled" is a predicative adjunct in your example. It's predicative because it relates to a predicand, i.e. "the furniture", and it's an adjunct because it's a modifier in clause structure, i.e. in the verb phrase. A non-predicative adjunct would, for example, be "The furniture arrives promptly", where "promptly" modifies the verb "arrives".

There's a question about "I woke up tired" on English Language Learners. I think there are several other similar questions both here and there, but not always easy to find; some ask why an adverb isn't used, for instance.

@BillJ Your comment would seem far more suited to the answer box.

@AndrewLeach Done!


The furniture arrives fully assembled.

You are right when you say that "fully assembled" is connected to the subject.
I would analyse "fully assembled" as a predicative adjunct here.
It's predicative because it relates to a predicand, i.e. "the furniture", and it's an adjunct because it's a modifier in clause structure, i.e. in the verb phrase.
A non-predicative adjunct would, for example, be "The furniture arrives promptly", where "promptly" modifies the verb "arrives".

Are we certain it's not a PC? It doesn't seem to front well, for example. Also "The furniture arrives fully assembled, and the fittings do flat-packed" doesn't seem to work.

Looks fine to me. The proform "do" is understood as "arrive". I take flat-packed and "fully assembled" to be predicative adjuncts.
